# Como pegar resolução de uma imagem?

Tags: c#

Como pegar resolução de uma imagem? Tenho uma aplicação web e preciso pegar esses dados de uma imagem no localhost.

Comment: Que imagem? Dê mais dados, coloque o que você está fazendo.

Comment: Tenho uma imagem no servidor onde está a aplicação. Preciso pegar esses dados (resolução) dela.

Comment: Isto você já escreveu, mas se você não der informações relevantes do que está fazendo, o que está usando, dando um exemplo de código, que recursos está usando, fica impossível responder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se for altura e largura, é bastante simples:

```
string path = @"C:\caminho\qualquer\minha_imagem.jpg";
var img = Image.FromFile(path);
// img.Width é a largura
// img.Height é a altura
```

Agora, se você quer os pixels por polegada (semanticamente mais perto de uma resolução de imagem), seria algo como:

```
string path = @"C:\caminho\qualquer\minha_imagem.jpg";
var img = Image.FromFile(path);
var graf = Graphics.FromImage(img);
var resolucao = (bmp.Width / bmp.HorizontalResolution) * graf.DpiX;
```